# binary file not found on doing go build -o /bin/go_docker inside a docker file

Tags: docker, go, lang

below is the content of the dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.8 as goimage

ENV SRC=/go/src/

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/

RUN mkdir /go/src/go_docker

WORKDIR /go/src/go_docker

RUN cd /go/src/go_docker

COPY StoreImage.go .

RUN go build -o /bin/go_docker

CMD ["/bin/go_docker"]
```

Docker build is successful for the above content.. But dont see the binary file generated in /bin/go_docker

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Where are you looking for the file? In the docker image or on your host system?

Comment: looking for the file in pod. 
Have deployed the image in Minikube

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `StoreImage.go` can copy into docker

Comment: can you provide more detail on how this might be done?  wouldn't the docker build be failing if `StoreImage.go` *couldn't* be copied in the container?  the OP states that the "build is successful"; please elaborate on what you think is not being checked

Comment: Docker file content is already shared in the query.

1. Docker file is built in minikube using this command - docker build -t app:v1 .

Below is the successful message for docker build

"Successfully built 88ea8c829e8d
Successfully tagged app:v1"

now am logging into pod to check if the binary file is generated in /bin/

Comment: root@image1-store-6bcdf89545-t7lfk:/go/bin# ls
root@image1-store-6bcdf89545-t7lfk:/go/bin#

Comment: It’s not going to be in `/go/bin`, it’ll be in `/bin` because you specified that absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Binary file is created in /bin location and go_docker is the created binary file.
.exe will not be the extension in linux whereas .exe will be seen only in windows